# Kafka server node goes down as with “Too many open files” error

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using 3 node Kafka cluster, with a total of 151 topics with 1 partition for each topic. And we have configured the replication factor=3. While we start kafka brokers getting following error:

```
ERROR Error while accepting connection (kafka.network.Acceptor)

java.io.IOException: Too many open files
```

Answer (score 2):

The default value of max. open files is 1024 on most Unix systems. 
Depending on your throughput you need to configure a much higher value.
Try to start with 32768 or higher

Comment: is there a way to contrain how many files a kafka producer can have open at one time?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is due to the less number of file handles.

Can you check the file descriptor limit as below

```
ulimit -n
```

Try changing the open file descriptor to a higher value:

```
ulimit -n <noOfFiles>
```

You can get the maximum allowed number of open files: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Comment: is there a way to contrain how many files a kafka producer can have open at one time?